# how do I color white zone using css

Tags: css

How can I color this white zone between these blue blocks please ?
I have this code

```
#nav{
    padding:0;
}
.rech{
    margin-left: 785px;
}
.px{
    margin-left: 3px;
}
#nav li{
    display:inline;
}
#nav li a, .rech{  
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   background-color: #0568CD;
   color:#ffffff;
   border-bottom:1px;
   border-bottom-color:#0568CD;
   border-bottom-style:solid;
}
#nav li a:hover{
   background-color:#9B1C26;
   padding-bottom:12px;
   border-bottom:2px;
   border-bottom-color:#000000;
   border-bottom-style:solid;
   margin:-1px;
}
```

Here is a screen-shot
http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2013/08/12/130812073042816473.jpg

Here is my HTML code,

```
> <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
>     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
>     <!DOCTYPE html>
>     <html>
>         <div>
>           <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/inc/form.css"/>" />
>             <ul id="nav">
>                   <li><a href="/projetForum/accueil" class="px">Forum</a></li>
>                   <c:if test="${!empty sessionScope.sessionUtilisateur}">
>                   <li><a href="/projetForum/deconnexion">Profil</a></li>
>                       <li><a href="/projetForum/deconnexion">Se déconnecter</a></li>
>                 </c:if>
>                 <c:if test="${empty sessionScope.sessionUtilisateur}">
>                   <li><a href="/projetForum/connexion">Se connecter</a></li>
>                   <li><a href="/projetForum/inscription">S'inscrire</a></li>
>                 </c:if>
>               <li><a href="/projetForum/contactus">Nous contacter</a></li>
>               <li><input type="text" id="rechercher" name="rechercher" value="Recherche" size="20" maxlength="20" class="rech"/></li>
>           </ul>
>         </div>
>     </html>
```

(formatted html code to show it in the post)

Comment: And what's your HTML? Can you post your HTML *here*, and construct a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show your code in action and so we can see what element you're referring to? For code-questions a picture is great to show what you *want*, but in terms of working out a solution they're practically worthless, I'm afraid.

Comment: Try adding `#nav{background:red;}` to color red instead of white

Comment: `body { background-color:blue; }`? (Not clear what the white bit is)

Comment: first do you want to color that white zone with blue???if so we need your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#nav {
  background: #0568CD;
  display:block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Setting #nav to block will make it full width, and overflow:auto means it will expand to the height of the floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{background-color:black}
```

this property define the color for your background window.

i make an example with black, but you can use every color you want.

Answer (score 0):

It makes it a bit difficult not knowing what your HTML structure looks like, but have you tried styling the ul?

```
#nav ul {
  background-color: #0568CD;
}
```

Comment: Since you're floating your `<a>`'s, the height on your nav, ul and li's might have collapsed. You may need to add an additional height to the `<ul>` as well. As a quick test, you could just say `#nav ul { height:30px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-color or background` css property on that element.

As I see you are using Google Chrome browser, press Right Click on the element that you want to color, and then click on Inspect element. This should show you for which element you have to add the style.

You could edit it fast and preview it in Chrome by using the Styles tab in the right side, but remember this will be lost when you refresh the page, so make sure you set it in your code too.

Examples:

```
background-color: gray;
```

or

```
background: gray;
```

The recommended way is to use `background-color` if you want just to set the color. Also it is recommended to use hex codes(Ex. *#cccccc*) instead of color names(Ex. *gray*) as browsers may render it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you showed us this on a JSFiddle or at least uploaded your HTML.

Anyway, I'd assume, from the information you gave:

```
#nav {
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Try <ul style="background-color:lightblue;" id="nav">

Comment: You are welcome. Please up vote and mark my answer as Green :)